# Derivative of an exponent

Tags: calculus

$y=x^{x^x}$

Find the derivative

$\ln(y)=\ln(x^{x^x})$

$\ln(y)=x^x\ln(x)$

To bring down the exponent of the $x$ I have to add another ln like this $\ln(\ln(y))=\ln(x^x) \ln(\ln(x))$

My question is : Do I have to add a plus between these two $\ln(x^x)+\ln(\ln(x))$ ?

Comment: Yes you do need it. $\ln(x^x\ln(x))=\ln(x^x)+\ln(\ln(x))=x\ln(x)+\ln(\ln(x))$

Comment: please use laTeX in the future. Is your question the derivative of $x^{x^x}$?

Answer (score 0):

From your calculations,

$\ln(y)=x^x\ln(x)$

$\therefore \ln(\ln(y))=\ln(x^x\ln(x))$

=$\ln(x^x) + \ln(\ln(x))$

[Since,$\ln(ab)=\ln a +\ln b$,taking $a=x^x,b=\ln (x)$]

=$x\ln(x) + \ln(\ln(x))$